# How to remove an item in an SQL database?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, delete-row

I know there are lots of threads with more or less same topic but none of them covers my situation:

I have delete button that delete one item in a listView but when you close the app and reopen it the items reappears. I don't know how to fix this .

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String ITEMS_TABLE = "items";

private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + ITEMS_TABLE + " (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "description TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "completed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";
    db.execSQL(createQuery);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

The button works fine but it does not delete permently I don't know if it is the code or if it is where I am placing it in my `MainActivity` if someone would please tell that would much appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "ToDoApp";

private ToDoListManager listManager;
private ToDoItemAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView todoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todo_list);

    listManager = new ToDoListManager(getApplicationContext());

    adapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(
            this,
            listManager.getList()
    );

    todoList.setAdapter(adapter);

    ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_item);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onAddButtonClick();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

private void onAddButtonClick() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.add_item);

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                            input.getText().toString(),
                            false
                    );
                    listManager.addItem(item);
                    adapter.swapItems(listManager.getList());
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton(
            R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    builder.show();
}

private class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ToDoItem> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ToDoItemAdapter(
            Context context,
            List<ToDoItem> items
    ) {
        super(context, -1, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void swapItems(List<ToDoItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ItemViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_item_layout, parent, false);


            holder = new ItemViewHolder();
            holder.itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            holder.itemState = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


       holder.itemDescription.setText(items.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.itemState.setChecked(items.get(position).isComplete());

        holder.itemState.setTag(items.get(position));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ToDoItem item = (ToDoItem) holder.itemState.getTag();
                item.toggleComplete();
                listManager.updateItem(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_Button);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                items.remove(items.get(position));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.itemState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ToDoItem item = (ToDoItem) holder.itemState.getTag();
                item.toggleComplete();
                listManager.updateItem(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}

public static class ItemViewHolder{
    public TextView itemDescription;
    public CheckBox itemState;
     }
 }
```

**ToDoListManager.java**

```
public class ToDoListManager {

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

public ToDoListManager(Context context) {

    dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
}

public List<ToDoItem> getList() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE,
            null
    );

    List<ToDoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")),
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("completed")) != 0,
                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))
            );
            items.add(item);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return items;
}

public void addItem(ToDoItem item) {

    ContentValues newItem = new ContentValues();
    newItem.put("description", item.getDescription());
    newItem.put("completed", item.isComplete());

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE, null, newItem);


}

public void updateItem(ToDoItem item) {

    ContentValues editItem = new ContentValues();
    editItem.put("description", item.getDescription());
    editItem.put("completed", item.isComplete());

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getId()) };

    db.update(DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE, editItem, "_id=?", args);

  }
}
```

**ToDoItem.java**

```
public class ToDoItem {

private String description;
private boolean isComplete;
private long id;

public ToDoItem(String description, boolean isComplete) {
 this(description, isComplete, -1);
}
public ToDoItem(String description,boolean isComplete,long id) {
    this.description = description;
    this.isComplete = isComplete;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return isComplete;
}

public void toggleComplete() {
    isComplete = !isComplete;
}
public long getId() {return id;}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return getDescription();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just remove items in your adapter class that causes the item delete from the current listView. but you have not any function in your `ToDoListManager.java` that remove items from your database. deleting from a listView does not affect to your database items.

you can add this function to your `ToDoListManager.java` class

```
public void deleteItem(long itemId) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE, "_id = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(itemId) }); 
}
```

and call it from your delete button's onClick, like this

```
ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_Button);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long itemId = items.get(position).getId();
                items.remove(items.get(position));
                listManager.deleteItem(itemId);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did as you said and it says can not resolve for items listManager.deleteItem(**item**.getId());

Comment: I edited my answer. try again

Comment: `listManager.deleteItem(item.getId());`
this can not resolve because in `onclick` scope `item` is unknown, it was typo in my first answer, you need to use `items` list in the scope

Comment: thanks for your great answer it works your the best! I am just wondering if I can add a little more functionality  with your help? i wanted to add  a Time stamp of when an item was added to the list. do you think you can help please?

Comment: I'm glad, I think it's better to ask another question and put link of your new question here, I'll answer to you in there. also please accept this answer if it's working.

Comment: OK thanks i will do that but i have to wait 90 minutes before I can ask another Question. i will put a link here as soon as I can thanks again for your help.

Comment: here is the link hope you can help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865645/how-to-add-a-time-stamp-to-a-list-view

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching the data from data base and displaying it in listview,you need to delete the row from database too. make a method in you database adapter that looks some thing like this:

```
public boolean deleteItem(Long id) {
        return Db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"_id="+id,null) > 0;
    }
```

then on list view item delete,simply call this method and pass the row id as argument.

Comment: i am new to this can you tell where do i add this bit of code please?

Comment: Inside your database helper class just like your onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods.