# how to add a time stamp to a List View?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, timestamp

I want to add a `timeStamp` to the `listView` so it shows you when the item was created in this code. Is there any way, I can go about doing this. if some knows how to do this please let me know.
**to_do_item_layout**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/delete_Button"
    android:src="@drawable/delete_item_button"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delete_item"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timeStamp"
    />
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todo.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String ITEMS_TABLE = "items";

private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + ITEMS_TABLE + " (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "description TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "completed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)"+
            "timeStamp INTEGER NOT NULL)";
    db.execSQL(createQuery);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)       {

 }

 }
```

The button works fine but it does not delete permently I don't know if it is the code or if it is where I am placing it in my `MainActivity` if someone would please tell that would much appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "ToDoApp";

private ToDoListManager listManager;
private ToDoItemAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView todoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todo_list);

    listManager = new ToDoListManager(getApplicationContext());

    adapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(
            this,
            listManager.getList()
    );

    todoList.setAdapter(adapter);

    ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_item);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onAddButtonClick();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

private void onAddButtonClick() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.add_item);

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                            input.getText().toString(),
                            false
                    );
                    listManager.addItem(item);
                    adapter.swapItems(listManager.getList());
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton(
            R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    builder.show();
}

private class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {


    private Context context;
    private List<ToDoItem> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ToDoItemAdapter(
            Context context,
            List<ToDoItem> items
    ) {
        super(context, -1, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void swapItems(List<ToDoItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        final ItemViewHolder holder;



        if(convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_item_layout, parent, false);


            holder = new ItemViewHolder();
            holder.itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            holder.itemState = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.itemTimeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);
            holder.itemTimeStamp.setText(getPassedTimeForCreation(item.getTimeStamp()));



            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


       holder.itemDescription.setText(items.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.itemState.setChecked(items.get(position).isComplete());


        holder.itemState.setTag(items.get(position));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ToDoItem item = (ToDoItem) holder.itemState.getTag();
                item.toggleComplete();
                listManager.updateItem(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_Button);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long itemId = items.get(position).getId();
                items.remove(items.get(position));
                listManager.deleteItem(itemId);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.itemState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ToDoItem item = (ToDoItem) holder.itemState.getTag();
                item.toggleComplete();
                listManager.updateItem(item);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}


public static class ItemViewHolder{
    public TextView itemDescription;
    public CheckBox itemState;
}
String getPassedTimeFromCreation(Long timeStamp){

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Long differece = now.getTimeInMillis() - timeStamp;

    if (differece < (5 * 60 * 1000)) { // (5 minute in milliseconds)
        return "5 min ago";
    }
    else if(differece < (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)){ // (2 days in millisecond)
        return "2 days ago";
    }else{
        return "long time ago";
    }
}

}
```

**ToDoListManager.java**

```
public class ToDoListManager {
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
public ToDoListManager(Context context) {
    dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
}

public List<ToDoItem> getList() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE,
            null
    );

    List<ToDoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                                           cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")),
             cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("completed")) != 0,
             cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")),
             cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("timeStamp"))
            );
            items.add(item);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return items;
}

public void addItem(ToDoItem item) {

    ContentValues newItem = new ContentValues();
    newItem.put("description", item.getDescription());
    newItem.put("completed", item.isComplete());
    newItem.put("timeStamp", item.getTimeStamp());

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE, null, newItem);


}

public void updateItem(ToDoItem item) {

    ContentValues editItem = new ContentValues();
    editItem.put("description", item.getDescription());
    editItem.put("completed", item.isComplete());
    newItem.put("timeStamp", item.getTimeStamp());


    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(item.getId()) };

    db.update(DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE, editItem, "_id=?", args);


}
public void deleteItem(long itemId) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.ITEMS_TABLE, "_id = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(itemId) });
}
}
```

**ToDoItem.java**

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public class ToDoItem {
private long timeStamp;
private String description;
private boolean isComplete;
private long id;


public ToDoItem(String description, boolean isComplete, long id, long timeStamp) {
    this.description = description;
    this.isComplete = isComplete;
    this.id = id;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;

}

public ToDoItem(String description, boolean isComplete, long id) {
    this.description = description;
    this.isComplete = isComplete;
    this.id = id;
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.timeStamp = now.getTimeInMillis();
}



public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return isComplete;
}

public void toggleComplete() {
    isComplete = !isComplete;
}
public long getId() {return id;}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return getDescription();
}

}
```

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoHjR.png)

[Todo_list_manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuNyl.png)

Comment: I have one question first before answering. you just want to show time stamp of item's data creation, or you want to show time of inflate of item in list view? are you want store time stamp in database or not?

Comment: it is a todolist app so every time they add a new to do item, i want to see the time I created it. (e.g. Added 2 days ago; Added 5 minutes ago).

Comment: so you need add one more column to your database to store user `toDoItem` creation. and for showing time in `Added 2 days ago; Added 5 minutes ago` format you need to write a function that compares items creation time by os current time and generate the proper string

Comment: I am writing an answer, it's take some time, please wait!

Comment: on problem thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this modification helps you, I just write the main parts, you need to apply changes yourself. good luck!

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + ITEMS_TABLE + " (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "description TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "completed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," + 
            "timeStamp INTEGER NOT NULL)";
    db.execSQL(createQuery);
}
```

**ToDoItem.java**

```
public class ToDoItem {
    private Long timeStamp;
    private String description;
    private boolean isComplete;
    private long id;

    // I just added two getter and setter methods
    public void setTimeStamp(Long timeStamp){
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public Long getTimeStamp(){
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public ToDoItem(String description,boolean isComplete,long id, Long timeStamp) {
        this.description = description;
        this.isComplete = isComplete;
        this.id = id;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public ToDoItem(String description,boolean isComplete,long id) {
        this.description = description;
        this.isComplete = isComplete;
        this.id = id;
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.timeStamp = now.getTimeInMillis();
    }

}
```

**ToDoListManager.java**

```
public List<ToDoItem> getList() {
    ...
    ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")),
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("completed")) != 0,
                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("timeStamp"))
            );
    ...
}

public void addItem(ToDoItem item) {
    ...
    // add this line
    newItem.put("timeStamp", item.getTimeStamp());
    ...
}

public void updateItem(ToDoItem item) {
    ...
    // add this line
    editItem.put("timeStamp", item.getTimeStamp());
    ...
}
```

**ToDoItemAdapter** class

I assume that you add a TextView `timeStamp` to your `to_do_item_layout` and your `ItemViewHolder` class

**ItemViewHolder** class

```
public static class ItemViewHolder{
    public TextView itemDescription;
    public CheckBox itemState;
    public TextView itemTimeStamp;
   }
}
```

**getView**
add this lines

```
holder.itemTimeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);
holder.itemTimeStamp.setText(getPassedTimeForCreation(item.getTimeStamp()));
```

**getPassedTimeForCreation(Long timeStamp)**

```
String getPassedTimeFromCreation(Long timeStamp){
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Long differece = now.getTimeInMillis() - timeStamp;

        if (differece < (5 * 60 * 1000)) { // (5 minute in milliseconds)
            return "5 min ago";
        }
        else if(differece < (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)){ // (2 days in millisecond)
            return "2 days ago";
        }else{
            return "long time ago";
        }
    }
```

> add getPassedTimeForCreation function in MainActivity class, not inside of MainActivity's function body!!!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    `...`
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    `...`
}

private void onAddButtonClick() {
    `...`
}

private class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {
    `...`
}

public static class ItemViewHolder{
    `...`
}

/**
 * this is the place that you must put the function!
 */
String getPassedTimeFromCreation(Long timeStamp){
    `...`
}
```

Comment: `getPassedTimeForCreation` function has low accuracy at the moment, for example if an item was created 6 min ago, it is return `2 days ago`, if you need more  accuracy you need to check more `if` conditions

Comment: where do i put **getPassedTimeForCreation(Long timeStamp)**?

Comment: you can put the function in `MainActivity.java`

Comment: I can not figure out your problem in last comment

Comment: sorry for the late reply. what I mean is the code is not working for  **ToDoListManager.java** it say unable to resolve for method.

Comment: I think you replace whole body of function, you should not do this, I just write the line that you must add it to you function. `...` means your code line, I didn't want to write whole function.

Comment: I know I did not do that. should I attach a image to the thread?

Comment: Yes, I think it's better way to explain your problem

Comment: OK give some time I am going to update the code with your solution and provide images where the code is not working on the thread.

Comment: I updated the code and posted the images. hope you can figure it out.

Comment: You have funny problems. You just need to add getter and setter methods for new attribute 'timeStamp' in 'todoItem.java' and add an timeStamp attribute to your holder class. I was thought you can do it and no more explain needed, please wait, I edit my answer and add remain part of answer ;-)

Comment: I am edited my answer and explain in more detail in codes. try again

Comment: still have problem with mainAcivity still not working I am going to update image for mainactivity

Comment: use the constructor `public ToDoItem(String description,boolean isComplete,long id)` and pass `-1`

Comment: i don't know if i am placing code in the right place. **ItemViewHolder class** is a new java class right?

Comment: what do you mean pass -1?

Comment: `public ToDoItem(String description,boolean isComplete,long id)` have three argument and you call it with 2 of them and third argument has been missing, I mean to use the function you have to pass third argument `id`. because of you have not any id when creating an item you can pass any long number as `id` eg.  `-1`, `0` ,...

Comment: `ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                            input.getText().toString(),
                            false,
                            -1
                    );`

Comment: I updated images again  and  main Activity code for places with problem in tread can you see if  **getPassedTimeForCreation(Long timeStamp)** is in right place in my main activity sorry to cause you so much trouble.

Comment: typically comments under a post must not be too much. I think you're not careful about my answer and you just copy and paste my code in your project! this image `http://i.stack.imgur.com/YoHjR.png` shows you don't define `itemTimeStamp` textView in your holder class. and you must put `holder.itemTimeStamp.setText(getPassedTimeForCreation(item.getTimeStamp()));` in a write place that `item` variable has been defined, means a few lines lower. and this image `http://i.stack.imgur.com/AuNyl.png` shows you don't create a constructor with 4 arguments in `ToDOItem.java` class